# Excel remove Characters past a decimal

Tags: excel

I have a large excel file the contains many way-points in Latitude and Longitude in the degree and minutes. My problem is that the numbers can't be rounded and must stay exactly the same, but the last 2 numbers need to be removed (in most cases)

I was wondering if there is a formula that would only allow three characters past the decimal. This is how most my numbers look.

> 26° 17.82964

However Sometimes they look like this

> 26° 9.82

I know I can format the cell as a number and set the decimal place to 3, however when I copy and paste it doesn't stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will truncate (It does not Round) the numbers and give all if less:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND(".",A1)+3)
```

[image]

This formula will round, but it will always fill out the numbers to three decimal places (I am aware the OP did not want rounding, this is for others that may want it.):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))&TEXT(ROUND(--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1)),3),"0.000")
```

[image]

Comment: Works Perfect Thanks!